# "named" iterators: zipping iterators to return values as a dictionary rather than a tuple

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to combine several iterators together, however instead of having a tuple, I would like the values to be "named", as in a `dict` or a `namedtuple`. This would allow to gain some abstraction and robustness, since I would not need to knowing exactly what or how many values are returned, and in which order.

Is there a standard way to do this in python?

Comment: why not creating a standard `dict` from the iterators? Like `dict(zip(iter1, iter2))`? Does it get any more standard than that?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You probably need to elaborate a bit in an answer. Where are the labels in your solution?

Comment: The keys in that example are in `iter1`, as the two are combined to form an [association list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found such a tool in `itertools`, maybe somewhere else?

In the meantime this behavior could be implemented with this short function:

```
def dictzip(**kwargs):
  for values in zip(*kwargs.values()):
    yield dict(zip(kwargs.keys(), values))
```

Then for example,

```
>>> name = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire']
>>> age = [11, 22, 33]
>>> email = ['alice@example.com', 'bob@example.com', 'claire@example.com']
>>> for val in dictzip(name=name, age=age, email=email):
...   print('{name} {age} {email}'.format(**val))
...
Alice 11 alice@example.com
Bob 22 bob@example.com
Claire 33 claire@example.com
```

This can also be used to iterate over a dictionary, "structure-of-array"-style:

```
>>> people = {
...    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire'],
...    'age': [11, 22, 33],
...    'email': ['alice@example.com', 'bob@example.com', 'claire@example.com']}
>>> for val in dictzip(**people):
...   print('{name} {age} {email}'.format(**val))
...
Alice 11 alice@example.com
Bob 22 bob@example.com
Claire 33 claire@example.com
```

*(Edited to integrate @YannVernier's suggestion on formatting)*

Comment: A good opportunity for using field names in a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings): `'{name} {age} {email}'.format(**val)`